# Laptop adapter using 802.11g radio protocol instead of 802.11n

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n, 802.11g

I have a HP Pavilion 15-p007tx Notebook PC which has a IEEE 802.11b/g/n wifi adapter. The speed of the connection is 50Mbps on the home network and the router supports 802.11n protocol. The laptops connected on the home network are connected using the 801.11n protocol and are able to get the full 50Mbps speed. Since my laptop uses 802.11g protocol the speed is restriced up to 25-26Mbps on the same network. I am unable to figure out the problem. I have updated all the network drivers still the problem is there. The laptop uses 802.11n protocol on college network and rest of the networks.

Comment: How do you know it's only using G?  Are you basing that off the speed alone or is a wireless utility telling you that?

Comment: What frequency is the N network broadcasting in? N offers two different frequency sets, and some N chipsets support one but not the other.

Answer (score -1):

802.11n requires either no security or WPA2 (AES-CCMP). Original WPA (TKIP) and WEP are not supported. Make sure you configured your laptop to use WPA2. Either WPA2-personal (WPA2-PSK) or WPA2-Enterprise (WPA2 with 802.1X authentication) is acceptable.

802.11n also requires QoS (WMM/802.11e). Make sure you didn't disable that somewhere like in your driver's advanced properties.

Also note that some cheap wireless modules may only do 1x1 (1 spatial stream) 802.11n, and perhaps even with only 20MHz-wide channels, which has a max data rate of 72.2 megabits/sec, which isn't much higher than 802.11g's 54 megabits/sec max data rate.